# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally. Dockerize Flask Application

Tags: python, docker, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying for over a week to dockerize a Flask application with the MongoDB database. My application has the following structure:

```
aplication
   - db
     Dockerfile
   - web
     app.py
     Dockerfile
     requirements.txt
   docker-compose.yml
```

This application makes web scraping using the selenium, selenium-requests and BeautifulSoup libraries. The problem I've been getting for a week is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

I've been trying several different ways to make the application's Dockerfile and I can't find one that really works.

My code is as follows:

- app.py

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from seleniumrequests import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_restful import API, Resource
from pymongo import MongoClient

app = Flask(__name__)
api = api(app)

client = MongoClient("mongodb://db:27017")
db = client.FlaskAPI

users = db["users"]

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
webdriver = Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
webdriver.get(self.url+'login')
webdriver.find_element_by_id("userName-id").send_keys(username)
webdriver.find_element_by_id("passWd-id").send_keys(password)
        
webdriver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@value="Login"]').click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(self.webdriver.page_source, 'lxml')

data = ''
        
        p = re.compile('var userParam=(.*);')        
        for script in soup.find_all("script", {"src":False}):
            if p.search(script.string):
                data = json.dumps(str(script.string))

data = remove_formatation_elements(data)
users.insert({"data": data})
```

- db Dockerfile

```
FROM mongo:5.0.3
```

- web Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install Chrome WebDriver
RUN CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE` && \
    mkdir -p /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION && \
    curl -sS -o /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    unzip -qq /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION && \
    rm /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    chmod +x /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver && \
    ln -fs /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver

# Install Google Chrome
RUN curl -sS -o - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list && \
    apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt-get -yqq install google-chrome-stable && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

- requirements.txt

```
flask
flask-restful
pymongo
bs4
selenium
selenium-requests
lxml
webdriver-manager
```

and

- docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  web:
    build: './web'
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    links:
      - db
  
  db:
    build: './db'
```

With the web folder dockerfile the chromedriver is created in the /usr/local/bin folder and the google-chrome and google-chrome-stable files in the /usr/bin folder.

So I can't understand why, even after so many different attempts, I can't get this code to work...
Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *WebBrowser* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

*A common cause for Chrome to crash during startup is running Chrome as **`root`** user (**`administrator`**) on Linux. While it is possible to work around this issue by passing `--no-sandbox` flag when creating your WebDriver session, such a configuration is unsupported and highly discouraged. You need to configure your environment to run Chrome as a regular user instead.*

Comment: Sorry for asking, but I did some research and still haven't found a way to run Chrome as a regular user. Would there be any reference that I could use to get dockerized this api, please?